# 2-valuation of a hidden integer

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $k,n$ be positive integers.

Let
${\displaystyle a_{n,k}=\frac{(3+2 \sqrt{2 k})^{n}-(3-2 \sqrt{2 k})^{n}}{\sqrt{2k}}}$.

$a_{n,k}$ is an integer (equal to ${\displaystyle2\sum_{p=0}^{n/2-1}\binom{n}{2 p+1} 3^{n-2 p-1} 2^{3 p} k^{p}}$).

How could I show that the 2-adic valuation of $a_{n,k}$ is equal to the one of $n$ plus 2?

$\nu_2(a_{n,k})=\nu_2(n)+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binomial expansion of $(3 \pm 2 \sqrt{2k}))^n$.  When you take the difference between them and divide by $\sqrt{2k}$ (which will give an integer for all integers $n$) you should find that the surviving terms will have different $2$-adic norms and all you need to do is pick the term with the largest norm.

Let's take $n=3$ as an example.  Expansion gives

$(3\pm2\sqrt{2k})^3=27\pm54\sqrt{2k}+72k\pm16k\sqrt{2k}$

Taking the difference and dividing by $\sqrt{2k}$ leads to

$108+32k$

where $108$ has two powers of $2$ thus $|108|=1/4$, and $32k$ has at least five powers of $2$ hence $|32k|\le1/32$.  The former term is larger in absolute value than all others, so the sums must have $\nu=2,|·|=1/4$ as claimed for odd $n$.

Try it for general $n$ and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks.  Miss one $ sign and the entire world turns inside out so that the core is now on the outer surface.  Or at least it looks that way on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I used the binomial expansion in my question after the "(equal to". But how do you get the 2-adic valuation of a sum?

Comment: If you have several terms and one of them has a larger norm than all the others, then in $p$-adics that larger norm term sets the norm of the sum.  Thus when rendered into $2$-adics, $|2|=1/2$ and $|4|=1/4$, and then $|2+4|=1/2$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.